# Function that calls two REST services and wait for both before return

Tags: node.js, loopback4

I'm developing a microservice in Loopback4/NodeJS and I need to call two REST services in parallel but return only when both returns. In this case, I need to create a new object from results and then return.

This is the signature of REST service function:

```
getUserById(id: string, attributes: string | undefined, excludedAttributes: string | undefined): Promise<UserResponseObject>;
```

And this is the way I'm trying to do (a sample code calling same service twice):

```
  async getUserById(@param.path.string('userId') userId: string): Promise<any> {

    console.log('1st call')
    const r1 = this.userService.getUserById(userId, undefined, undefined);

    console.log('2nd call...')
    const r2 = this.userService.getUserById(userId, undefined, undefined);

    await Promise.all([r1, r2]).then(function (results) {
      return results[0];
    });
  }
```

But it doesn't return anything (204).

I saw some examples around but it doesn't work in my case. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The code actually looks fine (except from being clearly a prototype). What's result of `await getUserById('someUserId')`? What happens when you add logging into that `then`?

Comment: Breakpoint hits the line next to 'then' but function returned before. @DazDylz answer is the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async getUserById(@param.path.string('userId') userId: string): Promise<any> {

    console.log('1st call')
    const r1 = this.userService.getUserById(userId, undefined, undefined);

    console.log('2nd call...')
    const r2 = this.userService.getUserById(userId, undefined, undefined);

    return await Promise.all([r1, r2]).then(function (results) {
      return results[0];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doing something, it is infact returning even the status code `204`, which stands for *"no content"* (list of all status codes [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)). So the status code pretty much implies that there is no content to be returned.

Comment: Yes, you're right, actually answer from @DazDylz is the solution. I didn't add return to Promise.all().